# Difficulty sorting a List

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list

```
h = [1001,
 862,
 757,
 681,
 602,
 530,
 501,
 461]
```

I've used this piece of code to try and sort it so that the list is reversed (461, 501, 530, 602, etc).

```
x = h.sort(reverse = True)
```

However, when I print x, it says "none."

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `.sort` is in-place sorting method. Instead use `sorted(Iterable,key,reverse)` function.

Comment: list.sort() function does not return list it just sort your list and store in the same variable

Answer (score 1):

`h` is sorted in place. The return value of `sort` is None, thus storing the result as `x` leads to `x` being `None`.

You can just print `h`. If you don't want to sort `h` in place you can
use `x = sorted(h, reverse=True)`.